# Sanity.io GROQ: retrieve documents that have a key defined inside array of objects

Tags: sanity, groq

I have documents that look like this

```
{
  "_type": "celeb",
  "name": "foo",
  "facts: [
    {a: 1, topics: {_ref: 'asd', _type: 'reference'}},
    {a: 2},
    {a: 3, topics: {_ref: 'dfg', _type: 'reference'}}
  ]
}
```

Not all documents have `facts` that have `topics`. Some have `facts` that don't have `topics`. I'm trying to retrieve the ones that have it. I tried the following GROQ query

```
*[_type == 'celeb' && defined(facts[*].topics)]
```

The problem with the query above is that it doesn't discriminate between `celebs` that have `facts` which have objects containing `topics` key, and `celeb` that have `facts` which *do not* have any objects containing `topics` key.

How can I make the query return only `celeb` documents that have `facts` which have objects that have `topics` defined?

Answer (score 3):

`defined(foo)` is just shorthand for `foo != null`, so that won't work. The solution is to count:

```
*[_type == 'celeb' && count(facts[].topics) > 0]
```

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work! You could change the string `topics` to any other string, i.e. `mumbojumbo`, and the query would return the same results!

Comment: Please confirm that you are using API version `v20210325` or later.

Comment: The above GROQ query works fine for me given your data. You can also verify this by getting the count back: `*[_type == 'celeb'] { "count": count(facts[].topics) }`. Perhaps you didn't show us the exact schema that you are using?

Comment: Here's the schemas https://github.com/hollowverse/cms/blob/main/schemas/celeb.ts https://github.com/hollowverse/cms/blob/main/schemas/fact.ts

Our data is public. The project ID is `ge8aosp3` and the dataset is `production` in case you wanted to query our actual data.

Comment: [This](https://ge8aosp3.api.sanity.io/v2021-03-25/data/query/production?query=%2A%5B_type+%3D%3D+%22celeb%22+%26%26+count%28facts%5B%5D.topics%29+%3E+0%5D%7B+_id%2C+%22topics%22%3A+facts%5B%5D.topics%5B%5D+%7B_ref%7D+%7D) works fine for me: It returns all celebs which has at least one topic under `facts`. If this isn't what you wanted, you have to be more clear. Note that you don't seem to have any `celeb` documents without any facts, so the inverse query doesn't return anything.

Comment: I just tried your query. It returned expected results, 14 documents that match. Then I edited your query and changed the string `topics` to `mumbojumbo` and it still returned 14 documents. I have no documents that contain the path `facts[].mumbojumbo`.

Comment: By the way, I made a few fundamental data migrations, the queries above are no longer relevant.